# How to install a specific version of postgresql using Homebrew that also includes bins like psql and pg_dump?

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

When I do `brew install postgresql` Homebrew currently installs `v10.0`. I need it to install `v9.6` so I did `brew install postgresql@9.6` but now there are no binaries like `psql`, `pg_dump` or `pg_restore`. I have the possibility to mix it up with `v10.0` by just installing both versions and then just run the server in `v9.6` and the binaries would be on `v10.0`. But I want to have everything on `v9.6` for now. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with homebrew but you can always install any arbitrary version from source. Compiling postgres is really easy.

Comment: I know but I prefer to use a package manager for that.

Comment: Yeah no prob, I figured that, just wanted to point out that postgres in particular is a breeze to compile if you get down to no other choices.

Comment: why dont you just uninstall not wanted ver?..

Comment: As I said, binaries are missing then.

Answer (score 6):

1. Install both versions of postgresql, present `brew install postgresql` and legacy `brew install postgresql@9.6`
2. Uninstall both of them afterwards
3. At `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/` you should have formulas files for both versions of postgresql, `postgresql@9.6.rb` and `postgresql.rb`.
4. Open both files to edit. Copy `url` and `sha256` values from `postgresql@9.6.rb` and overwrite with them corresponding ones in file `postgresql.rb`
5. Remove folder `/usr/local/var/postgres` (just to clear all the leftovers from previous installations)
6. Now install postgresql again with regular command `brew install postgresql`. Version 9.6 should be recognised from the edited formula file `postgresql.rm` and installed as latest.
7. As a last step you can pin your version of postgresql now `brew pin postgresql`.

With this procedure you have postgresql 9.6 installed with working CLI commands
[image]

Comment: It seems the changes will get stashed away by Homebrew.

Answer (score 2):

Versioned formulas are generally keg-only, which effectively means they are not symlinked into `/usr/local`. So you have them, just not automatically accessible. Homebrew should tell you that much in post-installation caveats memo (including additional manual setup options). Depending on your specific situation one of the following should work:

1. Add the keg binaries to your `PATH` variable manually, e.g. `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/postgresql@9.6/bin:$PATH"`
2. Force the symlink creation with `brew link postresql@9.6 --force`
3. Use `brew switch` if you have/need multiple versions installed

Hope it helps.